# Passing grouped_options_for_select to select helper in Rails 5.0.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My `select` isn't working and throws this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `marketplace_listing' 
for #<#<Class:0x007fe2a496e950>:0x007fe2920faf38>
```

I have this `select` in a form on a view.

```
<%= f.select :marketplace, grouped_options_for_select(marketplace_listing),
{}, {prompt: "Select your Marketplace", 
class: "icon_prefix input-field input-bottom-fixed down"}, required: true %>
```

`marketplace_listing` is a helper method I defined and looks like this:

```
module MarketplaceHelper
   def marketplace_listing
    {
      "North America" => [
        ['Canada', 'A2EUQ1WTGCTBG2'],
        ['Mexico', 'A1AM78C64UM0Y8'],
        ['United States', 'ATVPDKIKX0DER']
      ],
      "Europe" => [
        ['France', 'A13V1IB3VIYZZH'],
        ['Germany', 'A1PA6795UKMFR9'],
        ['Italy', 'APJ6JRA9NG5V4'],
        ['Spain', 'A1RKKUPIHCS9HS'],
        ['United Kingdom', 'A1F83G8C2ARO7P']
      ]
    }
  end      
end
```

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the helper in the appropriate controller

```
class YourController < ApplicationController
  helper MarketplaceHelper
  ...
end
```